# Ubuntu Samba server

Tags: samba

I have one folder for sharing on lan.
How can I set user permissions
for example user1 can read only  --- user 2 can write and read. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a share in smb.conf that looks something like this:

```
[Sharename]
path = /path/to/folder
read only = yes
guest ok = no
valid users = user1 user2
write list = user2
```